# Bind message has 2072 parameter formats but 0 parameters Postgres/Knex BatchInsert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, express, knex.js

I'm getting an error with trying to use batchInsert with Knex (Postgres DB).

It works if I'm inserting like 150 rows perfectly fine, but I've tried increasing the size of rows to like 7000 and I get this error:

```
bind message has 2072 parameter 
formats but 0 parameters
```

I'm assuming this has to do with the size of the data I'm trying to insert since this only happens when I increase the size to that amount, but I thought batchInsert was supposed to work for a large amount of columns being inserted. If not, is there a way to increase this size, or is there another way I need to insert that many rows?

Here is my batchInsert function:

```
async function create(req, res) {
  //create new asset in the system
  const chunkSize = 25000;
  const date = new Date();
  const result = !Array.isArray(req.body.data) ? { //stringify single asset history into json array
    ...req.body.data, history: JSON.stringify(req.body.data.history)
  } : req.body.data.map(data => {return {...data, history: JSON.stringify(data.history), updated_at: JSON.stringify(date)}}); //stringify each bulk asset's history into json array
  const data = await knex
    // .insert(result)
    .batchInsert('assets', result, chunkSize)
    .returning("*")
    .then((results) => results[0]); //return result
  res.status(201).json({ data });
}
```

I've randomly set this chunk size, but is there an actual specific number I need to set this too?

Any insight here would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: That clearly is a client bug, but I don't know if it is in Knex or the JDBC driver. To debug this, look at the PostgreSQL log for the statement that is actually sent to the database server. Please add it to the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Forgive me, but I'm not quite sure where to find the PostgreSQL log. Is this something that is stored locally?

Comment: Ask your DBA. If that's you, read the documentation.

Comment: Any resolution on this @LaurenzAlbe?

Comment: @BrandonMcAlees Well, there was too little information provided for me to give an answer.

Comment: Sorry, meant to tag @Treesap